# DateTime in sql in different localizations

Tags: c#, sqlite

In sqllite I have date and I have a query :

```
INSERT INTO stats_project_funds(id_project, id_funds, month,stake, stake_in_units,  stake_in_percent, profit, profit_in_units, picks, hitrate, won, draw, lost)  
VALUES(1, 5, strftime("%Y-%m",'27.12.2011'), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

As you can see date is in Russian format. My program is written in European localization where date format is 27-12-2011. What I have to change that this query will be for all localizations ? Now this field in the database is datatime type. Better solution will be change it to varchar and insert string value ? In field only year and month is stored.

My query looks like this:

```
DateTime newMonth = DateTime.Parse(month);
            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
            query.AppendFormat(" INSERT INTO stats_project_funds(id_project, id_funds, month,stake, stake_in_units, "
                + " stake_in_percent, profit, profit_in_units, picks, hitrate, won, draw, lost) "
                + " VALUES({0}, {1}, strftime(\"%Y-%m\",'{2}'), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0); ", idProject, idFunds, newMonth.Date.ToShortDateString());
            return query.ToString();
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not store it in normal DateTime and just do a format on the date that you want.? just curious why you would not use DateTime as your field type..

Comment: Now it is in normal DateTime and format is European, but this is the problem strftime(\"%Y-%m\",'{2}'), because in Russian version it should be strftime(\"%Y.%m\",'{2}')

Comment: DateTime doesn't **have** a format - it is just a number. I would simply defer any formatting issues to the app-tier, and let the DB just handle raw values (via typed parameters, as per the current answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use parameters instead String Builder, it is much cleaner, safer and less error prone. This way, you don't have to worry about date formats and this is the preferred way of working with parameters.

```
IDbCommand db = 
    new SqlCommand("insert into table (myDateField) values (@myDateParam)");
db.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@myDateParam", DateTime.Now));
```

Comment: newMonth.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) works in all countries :)